# Better option for case condition in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where using case condition makes query very lengthy.

The scenario is that I have columns like `QUESTION_NO`, `QUESTION_1`, `QUESTION_2`, `QUESTION_3`, `QUESTION_4` until `QUESTION_20`.

`QUESTION_NO` will have values between 1 to 20.
If value is 1 then I have to check if `QUESTION_1 != 'choose one'`.

Similarly if the value of `QUESTION_NO` = 2 I have to check for two questions `QUESTION_1 != 'choose one'` and `QUESTION_2 != 'choose one'`.

So if the value of `QUESTION_NO` is 20 then I have to check for all the columns `QUESTION_1` to `QUESTION_20` for value `!= 'choose one'`.

Is there any better way of doing this like using substring or something in sql.

Comment: I think you want to convert your columns to a separate table instead? That will make checking the questions (or answers?) much easier. `create table answers (question_no integer, answer varchar(64));`

Comment: Can you please share your query what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If the additional questions are all empty, then you can concatenate and compare:

```
where '|' || question_1 || '|' || question_2 || '|' . . . || '|' like '%|choose one|%'
```

I suspect this is the case with your data model.  As Corion mentions in a comment, you should fix your data model, so you have one row per question, rather than one column.  The query would be much simpler.

If the additional columns are not empty, then you can use regular expressions to pull out the first `QUESTION_NO` values from the concatenated string.